# Widget not constantly rebuilding + State issues

Tags: android, flutter, windows, dart, state

In my audio player I'm currently facing an issue. So how I set up the controls for the song (pause/play, rewind, etc.) is that when you click on a button, a modal sheet pops up. In that modal sheet you can see the slider, timestamp, buttons, etc. When I open the modal sheet with the song playing, the slider and the timestamp freeze and do not move. However, when I close it and reopen it again, the slider moves to reflect the current position of the song. (the slider and timestamp do not operate in sync with the song and only refresh when I close the modal and reopen it.) I've figured out the issue, which is that the modal sheet widget is not rebuilding every time the slider changes, but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm also facing another issue: when I switch tabs in the app with the music still playing, the **importfiles** screen completely resets and the player is disposed, causing me to re-upload all the songs again. And when I'm playing a song and delete another song while the first song is still playing, and when I open the song controls, the app crashes. Can someone please help with my issues?

**importfiles.dart**

```
// importfiles.dart v01.30.2024
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

class ImportFiles extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImportFilesState createState() => new _ImportFilesState();
}


class _ImportFilesState extends State<ImportFiles>  {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  PlayerState ps = PlayerState.paused;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  bool pressed = false;
  bool _isMounted = false;
  int songAdjust = 0;

  Duration duration = Duration.zero;
  Duration pos = Duration.zero;

  FilePickerResult? result;
  List<File> songs = [];
  late BuildContext context;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isMounted = true;

    player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((PlayerState s) {
      if (_isMounted) {
        setState(() {
          ps = s;
        });
      }
    });

    player.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
      if (_isMounted) {
        setState(() {
          duration = d;
        });
      }
    });

    player.onPositionChanged.listen((Duration p) {
      if (_isMounted) {
        print("Position changed: $p");
        setState(() {
          pos = p;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isMounted = false;
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void addSongs(File file, BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    setState(() {
      songs.add(file);
    });
  }

  void deleteSongs(int index, BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    setState(() {
      songs.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  ListView importedFileView() {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++)
          ListTile(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(ps == PlayerState.paused
                  ? Icons.play_arrow_rounded
                  : Icons.pause),
              onPressed: () {
                if (ps == PlayerState.paused) {
                  isPlaying = true;
                  filePlayback(i);
                } else {
                  player.pause();
                }
              },
            ),
            title: Text(p.basename(songs[i].path)),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.expand_circle_down_rounded),
              tooltip: 'Expand for song controls',
              onPressed: () {
                showSongControls(context, i);
              },
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void filePlayback(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < songs.length) {
      File file = songs[index];
      player.play(DeviceFileSource(file.path));
      setState(() {
        pos = Duration.zero;
      });
    }
  }

  String formatTime(Duration pos) {
    return pos.toString().substring(2, 7);
  }

  void seekToSecond() {
    int secondsToSeek = pos.inSeconds;

    if (songAdjust == 0) {
      secondsToSeek = max(0, secondsToSeek - 5);
    } else if (songAdjust == 1) {
      secondsToSeek = min(duration.inSeconds, secondsToSeek + 5);
    } else if (songAdjust == -1) {
      secondsToSeek = 0;
    } else if (songAdjust == 2) {
      secondsToSeek = duration.inSeconds;
    }

    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: secondsToSeek);
    player.seek(newDuration);
  }

  void sliderSeek(int secondsToSeek) {
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: secondsToSeek);
    player.seek(newDuration);
  }

  Slider audioSlider() {
    return Slider(
        min: 0.0,
        max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        value: pos.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            value = value;
            sliderSeek(value.toInt());
          });
        });
  }

  void showSongControls(BuildContext context, int index) {
    this.context = context;
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        double maxHeight = screenHeight * 20;

        return Container(
          height: min(180, maxHeight),
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(children: [
                Text(
                  '${p.basename(songs[index].path)}',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(" ||   ${formatTime(pos)}",
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255))),
              ]),
              SizedBox(width: 10, height: 5),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous_rounded),
                    tooltip: 'Rewind to the beginning',
                    onPressed: () {
                      songAdjust = -1;
                      seekToSecond();
                    },
                    iconSize: 40,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.fast_rewind_rounded),
                    tooltip: 'Rewind 5 seconds',
                    onPressed: () {
                      songAdjust = 0;
                      seekToSecond();
                    },
                    iconSize: 40,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      ps == PlayerState.playing
                          ? Icons.pause_circle_filled
                          : Icons.play_circle_filled,
                    ),
                    tooltip: 'Pause',
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (ps == PlayerState.playing) {
                        player.pause();
                      } else {
                        player.resume();
                      }
                    },
                    iconSize: 40,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.fast_forward_rounded),
                    tooltip: 'Fast Forward 5 seconds',
                    onPressed: () {
                      songAdjust = 1;
                      seekToSecond();
                    },
                    iconSize: 40,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
                    tooltip: 'Skip to the end',
                    onPressed: () {
                      songAdjust = 2;
                      seekToSecond();
                    },
                    iconSize: 40,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              audioSlider(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AlertDialog errMultipleFiles() {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text(
          "Error",
          style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255)),
        ),
        content: const Text("You cannot add the same file more than once.",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255))),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
            child: const Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Import Files'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255), Colors.black],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        List<String> allowedExtensions = ['m4a', 'mp3', 'wav'];
                        result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                          type: FileType.custom,
                          allowedExtensions: allowedExtensions,
                        );
                        if (result != null) {
                          String filePath = result!.files.single.path!;
                          if (songs.any((song) => song.path == filePath)) {
                            // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return errMultipleFiles();
                              },
                            );
                          } else {
                            File file = File(filePath);
                            // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                            addSongs(file,
                                context); // Use the imported ImportFiles instance
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.queue_music),
                      label: Text("Add a song"),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      label: Text("Delete a song"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (songs.isNotEmpty) {
                          // Show a dialog or some UI to select which song to delete
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text("Delete a Song"),
                                content: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++)
                                      ListTile(
                                        title: Text(p.basename(songs[i].path)),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          deleteSongs(i, context);
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          if (ps == PlayerState.paused) {
                                            player.stop();
                                          } // Close the dialog
                                        },
                                      ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        } else {
                          // Show an error dialog if there are no songs to delete
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text(
                                  "Error",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255)),
                                ),
                                content: const Text(
                                    "There are no songs to delete.",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 189, 131, 255))),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                                    child: const Text('OK'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (songs.isEmpty) {
                          AlertDialog(
                            title: Text(
                              "Error",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255)),
                            ),
                            content: const Text(
                                "You cannot add the same file more than once.",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 189, 131, 255))),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                                child: const Text('OK'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
                            filePlayback(i);
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled_rounded),
                      label: Text("Play all"),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Expanded(child: importedFileView()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**navpage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'homescreen.dart';
import 'importfiles.dart';
import 'library.dart';
import 'likedsongs.dart';
import 'search.dart';

class NavPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<NavPage> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    LikedSongs(),
    Search(),
    ImportFiles(),
    Library(),
  ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: PageStorage(
          bucket: PageStorageBucket(),
          child: pages[_currentIndex],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20),
              child: GNav(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                color: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                tabBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
                gap: 8,
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                tabs: const [
                  GButton(icon: Icons.home, text: 'Home'),
                  GButton(icon: Icons.favorite_border, text: 'Liked Songs'),
                  GButton(icon: Icons.search, text: 'Search'),
                  GButton(
                      icon: Icons.file_upload_rounded, text: 'Import Songs'),
                  GButton(icon: Icons.book_sharp, text: 'Library')
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

**main.dart (root of the app)**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'navpage.dart';
import 'importfiles.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BeatsMaster',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.atomicAgeTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: NavPage()
    );
  }
}
```

I'm completely stuck on the state management aspect and I tried many different things, like a provider and key in the superclass of the state, but it did not work.